# How to format text with multiple separators

Tags: awk, sed

I'd like to extract/format some text with `awk`.

The source text looks like this:

```
Section 1:
  main_command some_command1 some_subcommand1      # comment 1
  main_command some_command1 some_subcommand2      # comment 2

Section 2:
  main_command some_command2 some_subcommand3      # comment 3
  main_command some_command2 some_subcommand4      # comment 4

Section 3:
  main_command some_command3 some_subcommand5      # comment 5
  main_command some_command3 some_subcommand6      # comment 6
```

I want to know how to:

1. filter to the indented lines under `Section 2`;
2. specify which column I want (2 or 3); and
3. extract the comments (after `#` ).

For example, if I chose column 2 the output would be:

```
some_command2<tab>'comment 3'
some_command2<tab>'comment 4'
```

I've used `awk` to achieve `1` and `2`:

```sh
  awk -v RS='\n\n' '/^Section 2:/' "$path" | awk "/^  main_command/ {print $2}"
```

... but I suspect there's a better way to do it all without piping. Am open to using other tools (eg `sed`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this `awk` solution that works with any version of `awk`:

```sh
awk -v sq="'" -v OFS='\t' -v n=1 '
$1 == "Section" {
   p = ($2 == "2:")
   next
}
NF && p {
   s = $0
   sub(/^[^#]*#[[:blank:]]*/, "", s)
   print $1, sq s sq
}' file

blah7   'some comment 3...'
blah10  'some more comments 4...'
```

Using `n=2` for printing column 2:

```sh
awk -v sq="'" -v OFS='\t' -v n=2 '$1 == "Section" {p = ($2 == "2:"); next} NF && p {split($0, a, /#[[:blank:]]*/); print $1, sq a[2] sq}' 

fileblah7   'some comment 3...'
blah10  'some more comments 4...'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="\t" }
/^[^[:space:]]/ {
    this_sect = $0
    next
}
NF && (this_sect == sect) {
    val = $col
    sub(/[^#]*#[[:space:]]*/,"")
    print val, "\047" $0 "\047"
}
```

```
$ awk -v sect='Section 2:' -v col=2 -f tst.awk file
some_command2   'comment 3'
some_command2   'comment 4'
```

Answer (score 1):

One `awk` idea:

```
awk -v sec=1 -v col=3 '                                 # define section and column to process
/^Section/      { process= ($2 == sec":") ? 1 : 0
                  next
                }
process && NF>0 { split($0,arr,"#")
                  gsub(/^[[:space:]]/,"",arr[2])
                  print $(col) "\t\047" arr[2] "\047"
                }
' "${path}"
```

For `sec=1` and `col=3` this generates:

```
some_subcommand1        'comment 1'
some_subcommand2        'comment 2'
```

For `sec=2` and `col=2` this generates:

```
some_command2   'comment 3'
some_command2   'comment 4'
```

Comment: That would fail if the comment contained `#`s